# Ubuntu 11.10 powers down automatically

Tags: power-management, shutdown

Ubuntu 11.10 automatically powers down after a period of non-use. For example, I can't leave my computer on over night when I am downloading large files because it shuts down.

Is this a bug or is there a setting that addresses this?

Thanks,
Benjamin

Comment: this was a bug that was fixed with a new gnome-settings-daemon, make sure you're up to date and this should go away.

Answer (score 2):

Open Dash and search for *power*

[image]

Change your options as shown by the arrows.

N.B. since this is a beta - if the above does not work - file a launchpad bug report.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It must be a bug because this is what I see: http://ge.tt/9CROzK8/v/0